# How to install hbase on ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-9.04

How to install hbase on Ubuntu 9.04?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site meant for programming related questions, not for installing programs.

Comment: ServerFault is a site meant for system administrators and IT professionals related questions, not for installing programs.  Use SuperUser.com for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can install HBase in 3 modes: standalone, pseudo distributed and fully distributed.

Standalone mode is a much simplified installation, that only allows client code running on the same machine to connect. This is useful where, for example, you want to make a quick install of HBase on the workstation on which you are developing HBase client code.

Pseudo distributed mode is a "normal" HBase installation that runs on a single node cluster. This will allow you to install HBase on a single server in your office or data centre, for example, and then for client code running on multiple workstations to connect to it. This is clearly better in team development environments, but is arguably also better for single developer scenarios (where the server and client code are on the same workstation) because the developer can examine and consider all the system components that will be present in a production system.

Fully distributed mode is typically used in production environments, or for later stage benchmarking of a developed application, for example on EC2, and involves HBase running on multiple nodes.

In order to run HBase in pseudo or fully distributed modes, you must also install hadoop. hadoop is a distributed file system originally developed by Yahoo. HBase stores chunks of data in files, which it writes to hadoop. hadoop then takes care of replicating/distributing this data.

Because of the close relationship between HBase and hadoop, both systems must be installed correctly. The installation process may include making certain necessary changes to the default Ubuntu (or other server) configuration, as well as the software.

A quick guide on setting up HBase in pseudo distributed mode on Ubuntu is provided here http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/setup-hbase-in-pseudo-distributed-mode-and-connect-java-client/

Comment: Good answer, it clears up a lot. I know this post is a little over a year old, however, it should be mentioned even the author of the link you provided, says that they switched to Cassandra due to the complexities of the initial setup. Perhaps Cloudera makes installation simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Robert Berger has a detailed post on his blog.  [Check it out.](http://blog.ibd.com/scalable-deployment/experience-installing-hbase-0-20-0-cluster-on-ubuntu-9-04-and-ec2/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following article would help you to solve problems. Good luck!

[Experience installing Hbase 0.20.0 Cluster on Ubuntu 9.04 and EC2](http://blog.ibd.com/howto/experience-installing-hbase-0-20-0-cluster-on-ubuntu-9-04-and-ec2/)